# Heißt es "Geschichtebuch" oder "Geschichtsbuch"?

Tags: difference

Als Übersetzung von "history book", was ist richtig / falsch bzw. was hört sich besser an: *Geschicht**s**buch* oder *Geschicht**e**buch*? *Geschicht**s**buch* finde ich im Duden Online-Wörterbuch, aber auch *Geschicht**e**buch* bin ich begegnet, z. B. in folgendem Absatz:

> Im gleichen Jahr gaben Werner Tscherne, Josef Scheipl und Scheiterhauer Erich das *Geschicht**e**buch* „Geschichte und Sozialkunde“ heraus. Ein Jahr später veröffentlichten Arnold Schimpner, Harald Hitz, Herbert Hasenmayer, Senta Gähring und Manfred Tuschel und [sic.] dem Titel „Geschichte miterlebt“ ein weiteres Werk für den *Geschicht**e**unterricht*.
>
> <sup>Quelle: Wolfgang Bilewicz: *„Der Holocaust in Schulbüchern und Lehrplänen: Ein historisch-pädagogischer Vergleich zwischen Bayern und Österreich“*. Tectum Verlag, Marburg, 2016. Link: [Google books](https://books.google.at/books?id=ZgZ4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=Joseph%20Scheipl%20und%20Scheiterhauer%20Erich%20das%20Geschichtebuch&source=bl&ots=zs3i0wm2LO&sig=ACfU3U3nywKuliA3C-m2Wf-IC1IRwfOXWQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgq8eOhrbsAhXEqqQKHXUOCT0Q6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=Joseph%20Scheipl%20und%20Scheiterhauer%20Erich%20das%20Geschichtebuch&f=false).</sup>

Comment: Von wann und wo ist der abgebildete Absatz?

Comment: In der Schule haben wir das tatsächlich so verwendet, weil Geschichte hier den Charakter des Schulfachs mit genau diesem Namen hat und nicht die Disziplin an sich meint. Ich würde es allerdings mit Bindestrich schreiben, also *Geschichte-Buch*, genauso wie *Deutsch-Buch*, *Mathe-Buch*, *Religion-Buch*. Ähnlich ist das übrigens beim letzten Wort des Absatzes: *Geschichte-Unterricht* statt *Geschichtsunterricht*, weil auch hier das Fach, nicht die Disziplin gemeint ist.

Comment: @stephanmg: 20 Sekunden googeln bringen die Antwort. Ich habe den Link unter dem Bild eingefügt. @ Zweideutigkeit: Bitte zukünftig selber die Quelle angeben, denn oft ist es hilfreich zu wissen, wer das Buch verfasst hat, aus welchem Jahr es ist usw.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ja das ist richtig. Es war eher dazu gedacht, dem OP genau das von dir Gesagte ans Herz zu legen - aber implizit.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Nur dass es natürlich gar keinen Grund gibt, auch Mathebuch und Deutschbuch falsch zu schreiben.

Comment: Der Fragesteller hat sich nach einem (!) Tag aus dem Forum verabschiedet. Sollte man über die Gründe reflektieren?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In meinem Sprachgebrauch würde ich *Geschichtebuch* ausnahmslos als Bezeichnung für ein "Schulbuch, das im Fach Geschichte verwendet wird" verstehen. Ich entnehme deinem Zitat, das es sich bei deinem Beispiel genau um so ein (Schul-)Buch handelt. (weil du "history book" erwähnst: Eben nicht. Sondern "history class book")

> "Kinder, Pause ist um, holt euer Geschichtebuch raus"

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass ein ausgebildeter Historiker ein Regal voller "Geschichtebücher" hat (außer vielleicht, er schreibt Schulbücher).

Ein *Geschichtsbuch* ist dagegen jedes Buch, das sich im weiteren Sinn mit der Geschichte (Historik) beschäftigt. Ein Historiker dürfte viele davon haben. (das ist das englische "history book")

*Geschichtebücher* sind also eine Unterklasse der *Geschichtsbücher*, nämlich nur solche, die auch im Fach Geschichte als Schulbuch verwendet werden.

Comment: Überzeugende Erklärung! Ein "x-buch" (Deutschbuch, Sozialkundebuch, ...) ist ein Schulbuch zum Fach "x".

Comment: Die Frage nach der Korrektheit bzw. danach, welche Form vorzuziehen ist, wird hier ignoriert. Beim Lesen könnte man den Eindruck bekommen, *Geschichtebuch* sei eine übliche und akzeptable Art, Lehrbücher für den Geschichtsunterricht zu bezeichnen. Ist es aber nicht.

Comment: @DavidVogt Kannst du das beweisen? Ich bin anderer Meinung. Meiner Meinung nach ist "Geschichtebuch" eine vollkommen übliche und akzeptierte (und auch allgemein verstandene) Bezeichnung für ein Schulbuch im Fach Geschichte.

Comment: @tofro Das Wort ist einfach viel zu selten (nach Suche bei Google und in zwei Korpora), als daß es eine reguläre Bezeichnung für *Schulbuch für Geschichte* sein könnte.

Comment: @tofro: Es ist ein Beweis gewünscht, dass *Geschichtebuch* keine übliche und akzeptable Art&Weise ist, Lehrbücher für den Geschichtsunterricht so zu nennen? Wie wäre es mit der Tatsache, dass die deutsch-deutschen Online-Wörterbücher Duden.de, DWDS.de, zdl.org, de.wiktionary.org, corpora.uni-leipzig.de und de.pons.com - dieses Wort *überhaupt nicht* kennen?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Da steht (z.B.) "Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän" auch nicht drin. Trotzdem ist das ein (sogar ziemlich berühmtes), akzeptiertes, verstandenes und verwendetes deutsches Kompositum.

Comment: @tofro: hab ich jetzt nicht geprüft und vertraue der Angabe. Fair enough. Mein nächtes Argument zielt auf "und was wird damit im Alltag (heute noch) benannt?" - jedenfalls keine Kapitäne von Dampfbooten auf der Donau. Sondern die Tatsache, dass Deusch so wunderschön zusammengebaut werden kann. Gleiches gilt für Heizölrückstoßabdämpfung als ein Wort, dass schlicht alle im Deutschen verwendeten Buchstaben genau einmal enthält. Bekannt ja - sinnvoller Wörterbucheintrag nein. Ein generelles Wort für Lehrbücher für den Geschichtsunterricht an Schulen soll gleichermaßen exotisch sein? Don't believe.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Ich denke, du sollltest dich damit abfinden, daß es keine "nicht vorhandenen" oder "verbotenen" Komposita im Deutschen gibt. Und dass aus diesem Grund die meisten Wörterbücher darauf verzichten, Komposita überhaupt abzudrucken. Sonst wären sie nämlich (in jedem Wortsinn) nicht mehr tragbar.

Comment: Darum geht es hier aber überhaupt nicht. Es geht darum, dass meine Kinder ihr Schulbuch für Geschichte als *Geschichtebuch* bezeichnen und ihre Lehrer das auch tun. In meiner Schulzeit wurde das auch so gemacht - genauso wie das *Mathebuch*, das *Bio-Buch* und das *Physikbuch*. Wenn das in eurer Region und eurem persönlichen Sprachgebrauch nicht üblich ist oder war - dann ist das eben so. Daraus aber auf den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum schließen zu wollen, finde ich ein bißchen überheblich.

Comment: Also mit *unüblich* meine nicht, daß das Kompositum "verboten" ist oder daß es niemand benutzt. Ich halte die Form mit *e* für bildbar und verständlich – aber eben unüblich (ziemlich selten, vielleicht regional). Die übliche Form ist die mit *s*. Man vergleiche die Googletreffer für *Schulgeschichtsbücher* und *Schulgeschichtebücher*. (Und ich gehe bei dieser Einordnung nicht von meinem persönlichen Sprachgebrauch aus, sondern vom Studium der Suchergebnisse.)

Comment: @tofro: das Argument, dass es im eigenen Sprachraum gang und gäbe ist, habe ich in der Antwort noch nicht gefunden oder schlicht überlesen. Da lese ich nur "würde ich als Schulbuch verstehen". Mit dem Argument kann ich die Antwort besser einordnen und verstehen.

Answer (score 8):

In meinem Sprachgebrauch ist "Geschicht**e**buch" völlig unbekannt.

Ich kenne die Definition aus DWDS:

- Geschicht**s**buch = ein [Lehrbuch für den Geschichtsunterricht](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Geschichtsbuch)

  - also das, was in der Frage gesucht ist
  - verallgemeinernd auch als Kategorie für Sach-und Fachbücher, die die Historie von etwas beschreiben und kein dezidiertes Schulbuch sind
  - nicht zu verwechseln mit "einem historischen Buch" - das ist ein altes, originales Buch
- Geschicht**en**buch = eine [Sammlung von Geschichten](https://www.dwds.de/?q=geschichtenbuch)/Erzählungen jedweder Art

  - auch beim [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Geschichtenbuch)